# Upgrading CPU for Dell XPS 410

Tags: cpu, dell-xps, lga775

Is it OK to install an Intel® - Core™2 Duo E7500 Processor E7500 into a Dell XPS 410? It has a socket LGA 775 and 1066 MHz bus.

**Edit (from comment):** I currently have an Intel Core 2 4300 installed in my Dell XPS 410. If I install an Intel® - Core™2 Duo E7500 Processor E7500 will it be supported? The upgrade will cost me $125; is this even a worth while investment?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, the E7500 (Wolfdale) is a 45 nm CPU. They're not supported in the XPS 410.

Below is a list of ALL compatible CPUs, as of BIOS DXP061-020501 (which is the latest):

```
PR173 Presler P4 915, 2.80 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, D0
UY273 Presler P4 915, 2.08 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
YW816 Presler P4 925, 3.00 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, D0
XJ848 Presler P4 930, 3.00 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
PU963 Presler PD 935, 3.20 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, D0
DK050 Presler P4 940, 3.20 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
RT922 Presler P4 945, 3.40 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
UJ776 Presler P4 950, 3.40 GHz, 2X2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
CJ163 Presler P4 960, 3.60 GHz, 2x2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, B1

DK593 Cedar Mill 631, 3.00 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
PN407 Cedar Mill 641, 3.20 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, D0
PY394 Cedar Mill 641, 3.20 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
KU339 Cedar Mill 651, 3.40 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, D0
PY395 Cedar Mill 651, 3.40 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
DK594 Cedar Mill 661, 3.60 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, C1
DT883 Cedar Mill 661, 3.60 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, D0

HU587 Conroe E4300,   1.80 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, L2
DX483 Conroe E4400,   2.00 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, L2
RX522 Conroe E4400,   2.00 GHz,   2 MB,  800 MHz FSB, M0
DT893 Conroe E6300,   1.86 GHz,   2 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2
DU362 Conroe E6300,   1.86 GHz,   2 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, L2
DX485 Conroe E6320,   1.86 GHz,   4 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2
DU361 Conroe E6400,   2.13 GHz,   2 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, L2
KN977 Conroe E6400,   2.13 GHz,   2 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2
DX484 Conroe E6420,   2.13 GHz,   4 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2
KU345 Conroe E6600,   2.40 GHz,   4 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2
PN416 Conroe E6700,   2.66 GHz,   4 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2

WM543 Conroe XE X6800, 2.93 GHz,  4 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B2

FG941 Smithfield P4 820, 2.80 GHz,   2 MB, 800 MHz FSB, Mainstream, B0
UY272 Smithfield P4 805, 2.66 GHz, 2X1 MB, 533 MHz FSB, B0

HU585 Kentsfield Quad Core Q6600, 2.40 GHz, 8 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, B30
MP626 Kentsfield Quad Core Q6600, 2.40 GHz, 8 MB, 1066 MHz FSB, G0

UT713 Prescott P4 531,  3.0  GHz, 1 MB, 800 MHz FSB, ALT, G1
UT714 Prescott P4 541,  3.2  GHz, 1 MB, 800 MHz FSB, ALT, G1
UY274 Prescott P4 524,  3.06 GHz, 1 MB, 533 MHz FSB, G1
```

*[Source](http://en.community.dell.com/forums/p/19285839/19529800.aspx)*

Edit: an intensive search with various search engines did not yield any proof for a successful transplant of a E7500 (or any other 45 nm CPU for that matter) into an XPS 410.

Comment: Ok, one of you will have to specify a source, so we can know who's right :)

Comment: ever so vigilant, Gnoupi! :) the same question has been asked and answered in Dell's technical support forum. of course, if John T. has access to more reliable sources (not some SWAG :), unbeknownst to me, i will gladly delete my post to avoid any confusion here.

Comment: Different nanometer ratings don't directly break compatibility. You can use a 45nm core2duo or 65nm core2duo in motherboards with core2duo support. They are the same socket.

Comment: Nowhere on that page does it say those are the CPUs supported by the **latest** BIOS. He could have copied and pasted it from here: http://www.techspot.com/vb/topic94207.html . The latest BIOS is also DXP061-020503, not DXP061-020501.

Comment: you see ANY 45nm processor in this list? no ... and a recommendation to spend $125 (US, that is) based on assumption is quite irresponsible. post some proof that this particular CPU is supported in this particular computer and i will stand corrected. until then, my No stands fast.

Comment: It is supported in the computer, just maybe not in Dell's BIOS. But as I already said, those CPUs are from 2 BIOS revisions ago for one, and he doesn't have to use a Dell BIOS. Check the links in the comments on my answer from the Intel site.

Comment: got any '3rd party' BIOS proven to be working with and adding Wolfdale CPU support to the Dell XPS? throw in some Kentsfield CPU, slightly dearer, but it will run circles around the E7500 ... and the safer bet by a far cry.

Answer (score 1):

It MIGHT work, but it will be unsupported.

Generally, for a board to support 45nm Penryn CPUs, it has to have BIOS support.  Many things are possible.

-it just won't work
-it will work at 65nm Conroe voltages (could be bad)
-it will work and just not say the CPU name
-it will work perfectly (asssuming Dell has a BIOS for it)

I believe this is a 1333fsb CPU...if you put it into a board with a 1066FSB only, it will operate at a lower speed.

I would seek out a Core 2 6xxx series.  If you already have one of those, this upgrade is a big waste of cash.

Comment: "I believe this is a 1333fsb CPU". no, it's a 1066fsb CPU: http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SLB9Z

Answer (score 0):

If you have a decent CPU then you have a 775 socket, but you need the drivers 
and the BIOS updates for it to work. If you don't need to upgrade your CPU you should not. It is a lot of work. You are better off to upgrade other parts of your PC, like more memory.

Comment: Socket compatibility != actual compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has one of these going, I just did an upgrade to Q6700 Quad and it works beautifully. CPU score on Win 7 jumped from 5.9 (E6600 2.4) to 7.2. Idle temps range from 28 to 32 C. Load temps at 100% are in low 50's.

The CPU swap was very easy. Dell BTX systems are very easy to work on. Two screws to undo the heatsink, pop the old CPU out, put new one and lock it down. Clean heatsink with alcohol and then a few drops of Arctic Silver 5 on CPU and put the heatsink back on using the two screws. Easy money.

Found Q6700 on ebay for $26 with free shipping. Best bargain of all time. This isn't my primary computer of course, but it's nice to have it; I've always liked it, and now it has a new beating heart.